# Furnace reset problem

Tags: furnace

I have a new Goodman high efficient furnace model number GMH950703BXAG1. And this is the problem I'm having now:

1. Turn on the furnace power (after ~1 hour off)
2. Turn on the thermostat with Temp setting higher than room temp.
3. The inducer motor comes on, about 10 seconds later the ignitor lights up, 5 seconds later flames come on, and heat gets into the condo.
4. Furnace shuts off when set temp is reached.
5. After the temperature drops about 2 degrees, I can see the thermostat shows "heat" and hear the click from thermostat, but the inducer motor won't come on to start the sequence.
6. There is no power light or flashing light on, the furnace looks like is out of power, after I turn breaker off and wait a few minutes and turn it back on, then it goes to normal cycle one time,

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: You may not be waiting long enough for the thermostat's hysteresis setting. See: https://www.google.com/search?q=furnace+hysteresis&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb

Comment: Is the breaker tripped after the first cycle? Does the unit have power after the first cycle (you'll have to check with a multimeter or voltmeter)? Is there 24 volts at the secondary side of the transformer?